# Object.keys() returns unexpected keys on MongoDB object from collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Working with a strange problem here. This is an array of objects which is pulled from mongodb and passed into the following function.

I tried the following 3 logs sequentially within the `forEach` on the array pulled from the database:

- `e` (the object element within the array) which returns correctly. as you can see all the properties (keys) exist:

```
{ paid: false,   
  hotelWebsite: 'www.testing.com',   
  _id:5951848a24bb261eed09d638,   
  hotelAddress: '123 easy street',
...etc }
```

- `console.log(Object.keys(e))` is returning things that are not the keys...

```
[ '__parentArray',
  '__parent',
  '__index',
  '$__',
  'isNew',
  'errors',
  '_doc',
  '$init' ]
```

- and finally:

```
for(key in e){
    console.log(key);
}
```

which returns an absolute mess of data, part of which DOES contain the actual keys of the object:

```
__parentArray
__parent
__index
$__
isNew
errors
_doc
$init
id
_id
hotelWebsite
hotelAddress
hotelNumber
hotelName
courseCost
courseDate
courseState
courseCity
courseName
paid
studentComments
studentEmail
studentPhone
studentCountry
studentZip
studentState
studentCity
studentAddress
studentCompany
studentName
schema
constructor
$__original_remove
remove
_pres
_posts
$__original_validate
validate
toBSON
markModified
populate
save
update
inspect
invalidate
$markValid
$isValid
ownerDocument
$__fullPath
parent
parentArray
on
once
emit
listeners
removeListener
setMaxListeners
removeAllListeners
addListener
$__buildDoc
init
$hook
$pre
$post
removePre
removePost
_lazySetupHooks
set
$__shouldModify
$__set
getValue
setValue
get
$__path
unmarkModified
$ignore
modifiedPaths
isModified
$isDefault
isDirectModified
isInit
isSelected
isDirectSelected
$__validate
validateSync
$__reset
$__dirty
$__setSchema
$__getArrayPathsToValidate
$__getAllSubdocs
$__handleReject
$toObject
toObject
toJSON
toString
equals
execPopulate
populated
depopulate
```

And a relevant sample of the code if needed:

```
studentsArray.forEach( (e, i) => {

        if(task === 'nameTag'){
            console.log(e);
            console.log(Object.keys(e));
            for(k in e){
                console.log(k);
            }
        }
....
```

I need access to the properties (keys) for further processing within the `forEach` function. I am very confused on what is causing this and have never run into this sort of issue before. For the record the objects exist, using a `console.log(typeof e)` it IS an object (not a data "string"). I can access the properties using the dot or bracket notation but NOT using `Object.keys()` or `for (keys in obj)`.

Can anyone help me sort this out please?

Comment: `Object.keys` logs the keys of an object. That's what it does. The only way it "isn't working" is if something else overrided the native implementation. Are you including any polyfill libraries?

Comment: That's what I thought. I have used Object.keys() before and it worked fine. I do not even know what a polyfill library is so I think my answer is no unless it is automatically included in node. This is a node application that queries a database and then performs an action on the data.

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand now. The problem is actually `console.log` which is not standardized. The node version of `console.log` is likely truncating the keys to what it thinks are relevant when you log the object. The output of `Object.keys` is in fact the true list of keys for that object. If you edit the question I'll remove the DV :)

Comment: but it is not because I can not do anything to the keys. My goal is to take the keys, modify the key names and assign them to the previous key values then pass it into some other functions. But it fails because it can't access the keys

Comment: i need keyName+i where "i" is the index of the element in the array. so my goal is to:

get the current keys Object.keys(e)
modify them 
e[key+i] = e[key]
delete the old keys 
delete e[key]

then perform an action

Comment: mongoDB is holding an array of object elements. 
I query the database and get the array.

on the array I run a forEach loop with the argument "e" as the element (object) in the array

I am trying to get the properties (keys) of the element object "e" in the array that was imported from my mongo DB

Comment: I edited the title to be more searchable than "Object.keys() not working"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterates all *enumerable* properties, both own and *inherited*. This is not "a strange bug," this is in fact the intended behavior.

As for the `Object.keys()`, unless it was overwritten by a non-compliant implementation, those are in fact enumerable keys of the object itself, so you are most likely mistaken. The `e` object has a [`.toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) method in its prototype that is implicitly called when you do `console.log(e)`, so that is probably the output you are seeing there, and is not likely going to reflect exactly the same property keys as the original object. Try calling `console.log(e.toJSON())` and I'm guessing it will be the same output as in the first one.

If you want only the object's own properties, use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames).

If you want the keys printed in the first output, then use `Object.keys(e.toJSON())`.

Comment: I wouldn't consider the implicit call to `.toJSON()` to be necessarily odd. That method is intended to be used for  pre-processing an object into a suitable format for serialization, so it makes sense.

Comment: I have never before had to use Object.keys(obj.toJSON()) I was always able to just do Object.keys(obj). I still dont follow why exactly this is the case but I will accept that it works.

Comment: @vampiire I left [a link to when it's used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) in the answer. For example `JSON.stringify()` treats an object's `.toJSON()` as the replacer function during serialization.

Comment: thank you for the information. so this works in terms of logging the keys but it does not let me do anything with the keys. when I try to update the keys nothing happens. i give up man.

Comment: By "update" do you mean push back to mongodb? Yes, you'll have to make an update query to mongodb in order to do that, but if you mean something else, then your best bet is to store a reference to `e.toJSON()` so you can update that value. Make sure to re-initialize the `ObjectID()` before pushing it back to mongo, though. If you want a more elaborate answer, you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147987/discussion-between-vampiire-and-patrick-roberts).

Comment: The issue isn't with Object.keys() it's with the format of an object that Mongoose returns. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442920/mongoose-find-method-returns-object-with-unwanted-properties