# Can't access one property of an object, it is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am searching a MongoDB using full text. I can see my results with my score when I console log. However I cant access this property in my code

```
function bestMatch(name){

  ChebiEntry.find({$text: {$search: name}},
  {score: {$meta: 'textScore'}},(e,results)=>{
    if (results.length > 0){
      results.forEach((obj)=>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // This works, I see .score
        console.log(obj.score); // .score is allegedly undefined here...
      })

    } else {
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  })
  .sort({score: {$meta: 'textScore'}})
}
```

here is my output. As you can see, my stringified object contains everything I need. But when I try and read .score, it is undefined. All other properties work fine.

```
{"_id":"596d55fd2c446456a0ceb4be","id":3473,"name":"Cation","__v":0,"score":1.1}
undefined
{"_id":"596d560b2c446456a0cf10fc","id":23058,"name":"cation","__v":0,"score":1.1}
undefined
{"_id":"596d561e2c446456a0cfb067","id":36916,"name":"cation","__v":0,"score":1.1}
undefined
{"_id":"596d56032c446456a0ced48d","id":23058,"name":"cations","__v":0,"score":1}
undefined
{"_id":"596d561e2c446456a0cfb066","id":36916,"name":"cationes","__v":0,"score":1}
undefined
{"_id":"596d55fb2c446456a0cea1d6","id":4665,"name":"Divalent cation","__v":0,"score":0.75}
undefined
{"_id":"596d55ff2c446456a0ceccb1","id":9175,"name":"sodium(I) cation","__v":0,"score":0.75}
undefined
```

Comment: You know you can't read an object.prop after you've turned it to a string right.

Comment: @Darkrum You know JSON.stringify doesn't convert in-place, right?

Comment: @Darkrum Really? I have not modified the "obj" though. Regardless, I commented out my stringify line, and it still does not work. I also tried this: console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); 
        console.log(obj.name); 

and it appears I still can read obj.property after stringification

Comment: @Raven What if you'd `console.dir(obj)`?

Comment: @Teemu here's the kicker wheres obj? Ugh arrow functions...

Comment: @Darkrum It is in `results`, or "they", but it seems you've already found out.

Comment: @Teemu, here is what I see:

model {
 ...
  _doc: 
   { score: 1.1,
     __v: 0,
     name: 'Cation',
     id: 3473,
     _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: [Object] } },
  '$init': true }

I had to remove most of the model part because it won't fit in this comment. What are we looking for here?

Comment: It should work.  Possibly `obj` is an already-stringified representation?  Perhaps you should `obj = JSON.parse(obj)` and try it?

Comment: For clarification, I'm trying to extract all of my objects from results that has a .score of > 1.

Comment: Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lcdnau3x/) and see if it makes a difference? Also, the `return false` in your code seems misguided, the `find(()` function is async, hence the callback, and you can't return from that.

Comment: @James I don't think it is is already stringified. Why would it? I tried that line, it does not work. I'm totally confused =/

Comment: @adeneo "TypeError: ChebiEntry.find(...).toArray is not a function"

Comment: @Raven what does typeof say about obj?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) works and attempting to access to key directly does not, is because `JSON.stringify()` preprocesses the object using [`Object#toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior), if the method exists on the object. In order to solve your problem, you can do the following:

```
results
  .map(obj => obj.toJSON())
  .forEach(obj => {
    console.log(obj.score);
  })
```

[I've answered a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44833913/1541563), except that in that case, the user was attempting to iterate the enumerable properties of the unprocessed object using `for...in`, and calling `.toJSON()` on the object before enumerating its keys solved the problem.

Alternatively, [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28459390/1541563), you can just pass the option `{lean: true}` to your query like this:

```
ChebiEntry.find(
  {$text: {$search: name}},
  {score: {$meta: 'textScore'}},
  {lean: true},
  (e, results) => {
    ...
  })
  ...
```

and leave the rest of your code unchanged, meaning you won't have to explicitly call `toJSON()` on your objects.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you, that worked. My intention for iterating over this object was to create an array of objects that have a score > 1, then pass that somewhere else. Can you please comment on the best approach for this problem? However, since you did answer the question I posted, I have accepted it -- thank you!

Comment: @Raven my understanding is that `{lean: true}` comes with a performance boost of up to 3x, based on the answer I cited, but I cannot confirm this, I'm just repeating what was claimed by that answerer.

Comment: And is the reason this works that Mongo returns either a special object or a cursor, not a regular object containing the data ?

Comment: @Patrick Roberts

Thanks, that also worked w/o needing to modify my code. I never knew Javascript could get this confusing

Comment: @adeneo yes, it contains several properties that implement its cursor functionality, as shown in the [first question I cited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44833736/1541563). You can see all the methods that user was able to access on the object and didn't want to.