# mongoose find() returns properties of model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to find a existing user using mongoose 
My query is

```
UserAccount.find(variables, function (error, success) {
            if (error) {
                response.send({status: false});
            } else {
                console.log(success);
            }
        });
```

If user exists means it returns following array.

```
[ model {
        '$__':
         InternalCache {
           strictMode: true,
           selected: [Object],
           shardval: undefined,
           saveError: undefined,
           validationError: undefined,
           adhocPaths: undefined,
           removing: undefined,
           inserting: undefined,
           saving: undefined,
           version: undefined,
           getters: {},
           _id: 5c98e64f2106e94022532c9f,
           populate: undefined,
           populated: undefined,
           wasPopulated: false,
           scope: undefined,
           activePaths: [StateMachine],
           pathsToScopes: {},
           session: null,
           ownerDocument: undefined,
           fullPath: undefined,
           emitter: [EventEmitter],
           '$options': [Object] },
        isNew: false,
        errors: undefined,
        _doc:
         { isActive: true,
           _id: 5c98e64f2106e94022532c9f,
           userName: 'buyer@mysite.com',
           password:
            '$2a$05$vpowA76cB3T/4eHGbQPqd.F/iIebX7SXKPZA2k1wcmlSIDks0q852',
           userCategory: 'buyer',
           createdDate: 2019-03-20T14:31:43.250Z,
           updatedDate: 2019-03-20T14:31:43.250Z,
           __v: 0 },
        '$init': true } ]
```

I don't know what is causing this problem? Until yesterday it returned only the user data, but this is so strange to me. How to fix this problem? Can some one help me to fix this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also faced the same issue, the probelm is If your using latest version of mongo with the older mongoose , this can be solved by installing the newer mongoose version and run the mongoose find(), this will solve your probelm.

Comment: Yes I reinstalled my os and every thing completely. Updating the mongoose solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You simply get rid this by using lean() at the end of query

```
const courses = await Course
    .find({ isPublished: true })
    .or([
        { price: { $gte: 15 } },
        { name: /.*by.*/i }
    ]).lean(); // use lean to remove unnecessary values from output
```

Comment: This is the easiest and best way to get unstructured JSON to clear output in Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

The extra properties you were getting originally are due to the fact that results is a collection of model instances that come with additional properties and methods that aren't available on normal objects. 
you can pass `{lean: true}` as an optiont get plain object without all of those additional properties and methods.

```
UserAccount.find(variables, {lean: true}, function (error, success) {
            if (error) {
                response.send({status: false});
            } else {
                console.log(success);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried that too by referring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442920/mongoose-find-method-returns-object-with-unwanted-properties but it didn't work